# How to send a message from python script to a flask-socketio server (on the same computer)?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

So trying to figure this out:

I have a python script that is listening to some event on a website (using the websites APIs). I then want to send that event to a simple website via flask-socketio webserver.

`[python website listening server] -> [python flask-socketio server] -> [webpage]`

I know how to do [python flask-socketio server] -> [webpage]. Just struggling with the first bit; [python website listening server] -> [python flask-socketio server].

Can anyone point me in the right direction?